# Help With Construction of DID MLR Model - Dataset Contains 20.2 Million Observations

Tags: r, multiple-regression, difference-in-difference

First: apologies in advance for the length of this post. I am just attempting to provide as much detail as possible.

I am in the middle of a research study using Zillow ZTRAX data.

I am using Assessed Home Values from the data to explore whether or not the construction of SoFi Stadium in Los Angeles impacted home values based on proximity to the location of the stadium.

Here is  look at the data I am looking at.

I currently have 20,299,879 observations of this.

The 'distance' variable is the distance, in miles, the house is from SoFi Stadium.

```
 TotalAssessedValue AssessmentYear TotalBedrooms BuildingAreaSqFt  distance BuildingAge
1               7357           2018             0             1040  9.706832          49
2              81976           2018             2             1633 15.349301          79
3             262723           2018             2             1003 17.491314          75
4             358704           2018             2             1455 19.894094          63
5             389676           2018             6             4041  1.996699          66
6            5303077           2018             5             6917 13.869397          27
```

**My goal, using this data, is to use a DID approach to determine if the assessed value of those houses closer to the construction site of SoFi Stadium were impacted differently than those further away.**

To start, I created the treatment variables:

```
did.coding$post14 = as.numeric(combined.data$AssessmentYear >= 2014)
did.coding$over5 = as.numeric(combined.data$distance >= 5)
```

Construction of SoFi Stadium started in 2014 ... and I have randomly picked 5 miles. I am still not sure if there is a better way to do this or not.

After that:

```
mean.info = aggregate(did.coding$TotalAssessedValue, list(did.coding$AssessmentYear, did.coding$over5 == 1), mean)
names(mean.info) = c("Year", "Over 5 Miles", "Value")
mean.info$Treatment[1:9] = "Under 5 Miles"
mean.info$Treatment[10:18] = "Over 5 Miles"
```

I am gathering the yearly averages of assessed value for those homes under five miles away from SoFi Stadium and those over five miles away.

And, if you are interested, here is the plot:

[image]

After that, I did the following DID regression model:

```
regression.model = lm(TotalAssessedValue ~ post14 + over5 + post14*over5 + TotalBedrooms +
                    BuildingAge + BuildingAreaSqFt, data = did.coding)
```

... with the following results:

```
Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-442056310    -185108     -65044      76741 1222247947 

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       1.402e+05  2.632e+03   53.265  < 2e-16 ***
post14            4.381e+04  2.978e+03   14.712  < 2e-16 ***
over5             5.666e+04  2.267e+03   24.997  < 2e-16 ***
TotalBedrooms    -1.518e+03  2.154e+02   -7.049 1.81e-12 ***
BuildingAge      -1.881e+03  1.745e+01 -107.807  < 2e-16 ***
BuildingAreaSqFt  1.467e+02  4.280e-02 3427.851  < 2e-16 ***
post14:over5      5.172e+04  3.097e+03   16.700  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1842000 on 20299872 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.3699,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.3699 
F-statistic: 1.987e+06 on 6 and 20299872 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

And this is where I get lost.

It doesn't seem "correct" that *every* coefficient has a significant relationship.

Moreover, **I don't know how to interest this in terms of deciding whether or not the construction of SoFi Stadium impacted assessment values based on proximity to the construction site.**

As you can probably tell, I am a newbie to the world of statistics. Any help and/or advice you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

**Following up on Thomas' answer from below**

First and foremost, I have since switched to using sales transactions rather than assessments/value.

I have not done it yet, but it seems that a log transformation on the SalesPrice variable might be a good idea?

Anyways ...

I created a distance_ord variable as seen below. I also limited the distance to just those houses within 50 miles of SoFi Stadium and ran the lm model.

```
sofi.cleaned <- sofi.cleaned %>%
  mutate(
    distance_ord = case_when(
      distance <= 5 ~ "Short",
      distance >= 6 & distance <= 10 ~ "Moderate",
      distance >= 11 & distance <= 20 ~ "Long",
      distance >= 21 ~ "Very Long"
    )
  )

model<- lm(SalesPrice ~ distance_ord * post14 + age + TotalBedrooms + TotalCalculatedBath + SqFt, data = sofi.cleaned)
```

The summary of the model is as follows:

```
Call:
lm(formula = SalesPrice ~ distance_ord * post14 + age + TotalBedrooms + 
    TotalCalculatedBath + SqFt, data = sofi.cleaned)

Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-22687953   -191325    -70854     79903 590473400 

Coefficients:
                                Estimate  Std. Error t value             Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                   -43933.876    9218.212   -4.77          0.000001879 ***
distance_ordModerate          -28619.902   36953.243   -0.77               0.4386    
distance_ordShort            -168079.774   38853.043   -4.33          0.000015182 ***
distance_ordVery Long         -24318.502    7809.238   -3.11               0.0018 ** 
post14                        338533.332   17388.591   19.47 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
age                              294.311      52.991    5.55          0.000000028 ***
TotalBedrooms                 -31459.579    1149.883  -27.36 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
TotalCalculatedBath           223670.163    1471.150  152.04 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
SqFt                              23.490       0.548   42.87 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
distance_ordModerate:post14   982868.946   80733.722   12.17 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
distance_ordShort:post14       33130.389   85322.558    0.39               0.6978    
distance_ordVery Long:post14    5041.045   17530.608    0.29               0.7737    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1070000 on 1613414 degrees of freedom
  (17903 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.0438,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.0438 
F-statistic: 6.72e+03 on 11 and 1613414 DF,  p-value: <0.0000000000000002
```

However, I'm not sure how to interpret the results. Is this indicating that those houses *closest* to SoFi Stadium sold for $33,130 more relative to the same distance PRIOR to 2014?

And what do I make of the post-14 moderate number? $982,868 seems like a massive jump ... but it does make me think that it highlights that homes closer to the stadium were, in fact, impacted.

Again: sorry for such "newbie" questions. Still trying to wrap my head around all these numbers.

### Results from Example Code Below

```
Call:
lm(formula = SalesPrice ~ relevel(distance_ord, ref = "Short") * 
    post14 + age + TotalBedrooms + TotalCalculatedBath + SqFt, 
    data = sofi.cleaned)

Residuals:
       Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
-169836430    -228399     -80839      98344  850249201 

Coefficients:
                                                         Estimate   Std. Error t value             Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                                            300059.806    34715.472    8.64 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
relevel(distance_ord, ref = "Short")Long               117186.084    36201.104    3.24               0.0012 ** 
relevel(distance_ord, ref = "Short")Moderate           194567.265    40655.428    4.79     0.00000170352563 ***
relevel(distance_ord, ref = "Short")Very Long           90048.484    33971.768    2.65               0.0080 ** 
post14                                                2720212.663    66303.285   41.03 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
age                                                     -4212.732      135.232  -31.15 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
TotalBedrooms                                          -78360.880     2900.903  -27.01 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
TotalCalculatedBath                                    108009.017     3824.110   28.24 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
SqFt                                                      123.688        0.314  394.08 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
relevel(distance_ord, ref = "Short")Long:post14       -517920.013    72543.501   -7.14     0.00000000000094 ***
relevel(distance_ord, ref = "Short")Moderate:post14   3391377.359    80333.277   42.22 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
relevel(distance_ord, ref = "Short")Very Long:post14 -2305100.215    66570.242  -34.63 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2920000 on 1721661 degrees of freedom
  (27894 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.117, Adjusted R-squared:  0.117 
F-statistic: 2.08e+04 on 11 and 1721661 DF,  p-value: <0.0000000000000002
```

Comment: Welcome. So you're observing about 1.5 million homes over a 12-year period? Why did you pick 5 miles as the demarcation line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It doesn't seem "correct" that every coefficient has a significant relationship.

Why not?

It seems acceptable to me. Be mindful, you're observing over one million households over time. As your sample size gets larger and larger, you're able to detect smaller and smaller effects. It is your job to defend the practical importance of the results, in particular the effect associated with your interaction term.

Peruse this [article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3444174/) in your free time.

> Moreover, I don't know how to interpret this in terms of deciding whether or not the construction of SoFi Stadium impacted assessment values based on proximity to the construction site.

Your results suggest homes beyond the 5-mile periphery were appraised at a higher value post-construction relative to other homes. The difference *is* highly statistically significant. But is the $51,720 positive difference a meaningful effect? Ultimately, this is for you to justify to your audience.

One criticism you might face is your choice of the 5-mile cutoff for treatment assignment. Why did you 'randomly' choose this distance? I haven't reviewed any research in this area, but maybe others have theorized about the relationship between a home's value and its proximity to a major entertainment center. Ultimately, this is a content-area question, not a statistical matter.

It seems sensible to force homes *in the vicinity* of the construction site to be your reference group, but it doesn't have to work that way. You could certainly assign homes in the vicinity of SoFi stadium to be the "treated" group. I suppose it's safe to theorize that the more proximate properties experience the negative externalities of construction, such that assessed value may depreciate after the stadium is erected relative to the more distant properties. If you do decide to swap the groups, then only the interpretation will change.

I would suggest exploiting the granularity of your `distance` measure at bit more. It might be a worthwhile endeavor to investigate effects as you move farther and farther away from the stadium. One technique is to partition homes into different 'treatment groups' based upon their relative distance from the stadium. First, categorically define your groups. Here is one of several possible approaches:

- Reference (Short) : 0–5 miles
- Treatment 1 (Moderate) : 6–10 miles
- Treatment 2 (Long) : 11–20 miles
- Treatment 3 (Very Long) : 21+ miles

I view this as a series of concentric circles (i.e., "treatment zones") with the stadium serving as the focal point. Next, multiply each treatment group with a time dummy distinguish pre- versus post-treatment. The "timing" of construction is standardized, so you can still proceed with the classical difference-in-differences approach.

To set this up in software, all you need to do is differentiate the groups according to your `distance` measure. All homes should fall into one of the pre-determined groups, without overlap. Suppose we call the new variable `distance_ord` to represent the ordered nature of radii from the focal point. Once you instantiate a column with the appropriate categorical labels, simply interact it with `post14`. See the example code below:

```
# Create a treatment variable with more than one level
# It should appropriately label houses with different radial distances from the stadium

distance_ord <- c("short", "moderate", "long", "very long")

# Interact the multi-valued treatment variable (i.e., "distance_ord") with a post-treatment indicator
# Software will pairwise estimate all interactions and their constituent terms

model <- lm(value ~ distance_ord * post14 + covariates, data = ...)
```

Note, with four "groups" you're making three contrasts. Assuming the properties in the vicinity of SoFi stadium serve as your reference group, here are the contrasts:

- `"moderate"` versus `"short"`
- `"long"` versus `"short"`
- `"very long"` versus `"short"`

The foregoing approach is just another avenue for you to consider. My decision to delimit the groups in this manner is somewhat arbitrary, but I would argue it further exploits the ordered nature of the `distance` variable. It is analogous to assessing a *dose treatment*.

Another approach to consider is investigating the 'time dependency' before effects are realized. Is it often impractical to assume effects emerge instantaneously, especially during the construction phase. Graphically, it appears effects materialize with a bit of a lag. In practice, you could investigate lagged effects by interacting `over5` with *separate* year indicators from 2014 onward. Alternatively, you might also consider saturating the model with a full series of year indicators. This has the added benefit of serving as a check on the validity of the difference-in-differences design. In practice, it would amount to interacting your treatment dummy with a factorized version of time. See below for example code:

```
model <- lm(value ~ over5 * as.factor(year) + covariates, data = ...)
```

The coefficients *before* 2014 are often referred to as "lead" effects. You shouldn't observe any *strong* non-zero effects in the years before the stadium was erected. Focus more on the *magnitude* of the observed effects, less so on their statistical significance.

The year SoFi Stadium was erected (i.e., 2014) is referred to as the "immediate effect" of construction on home value. The coefficients on the interactions terms after the initial treatment year are often referred to as "lags" of treatment. It might be the first, second, or even third "lag" before you observe a meaningful difference. Again, don't obsess over the number of stars (i.e., `*`, `**`, `***`) next to your $p$-value in any one period. Rather, the purpose of this endeavor is to see *when* effects concentrate.

I hope you find some of these approaches useful.

---

### Example Code:

As requested, here is some example code:

```
### Method 1

# Keeping your original setup
# Use factor() as a wrapper around distance_ord
# Set the reference level inside of the relevel() function
# The relevel() function only works with factors
# Note the relevel() function is specified inside of the lm() function
# This is useful as it does not modify the original data frame

sofi.cleaned <- sofi.cleaned %>%
  mutate(distance_ord = factor(
    case_when(
      distance <= 5                   ~ "Short",
      distance >= 6 & distance <= 10  ~ "Moderate",
      distance >= 11 & distance <= 20 ~ "Long",
      distance >= 21                  ~ "Very Long"
      )
    )
  )

model <- lm(SalesPrice ~ relevel(distance_ord, ref = "Short") * post14 + age + TotalBedrooms + TotalCalculatedBath + SqFt, data = sofi.cleaned)

### Method 2

# Load the forcats package
# Assign the labels
# Feed it to the fct_relevel() function
# The level "short" is the reference group
# This function allows you to move any number of levels to any location
# The output has a meaningful order

sofi.cleaned <- sofi.cleaned %>%
  mutate(distance_ord =
           case_when(
             distance <= 5                   ~ "Short",
             distance >= 6 & distance <= 10  ~ "Moderate",
             distance >= 11 & distance <= 20 ~ "Long",
             distance >= 21                  ~ "Very Long"
             )
         )

library(forcats)

labels <- c("Short", "Moderate", "Long", "Very Long")  # "Short" is the referent

sofi.cleaned <- sofi.cleaned %>%
  mutate(
    treatment_zones = fct_relevel(distance_ord, labels)
  )

model <- lm(SalesPrice ~ treatment_zones * post14 + age + TotalBedrooms + TotalCalculatedBath + SqFt, data = sofi.cleaned)
```

Again, note the contrasts. All households in close proximity to the stadium serve as your reference group. You're comparing all households *within* each respective "treatment zone" with the omitted group. I assume your goal is to assess differences in value as you move farther and farther away from the stadium. If so, this is one way to do it.

Comment: sorry I am just now seeing this. I cannot thank you enough for this. Tremendously helpful for somebody getting into statistical studies for the first time!

Comment: No problem. If my answer cleared things up, then please give it a check. To offer further insight, don't drive yourself nuts with assessing significance levels. Suppose you interacted `over5` with a full set of year dummies. In practice, you are almost certain to fail a test of *trend equivalence* in the years *before* the stadium was erected, in part due to your extremely large sample size. Focus more on the magnitude of observed effects and how they differ pre- versus post-treatment.

Comment: Hi again, Thomas. If you don't mind, I actually updated the original post to include your first suggestion ... but now I have even more questions regarding how to interpret the model summary.

Comment: Remember this is just one variation of a general theme. My first question is, shouldn’t “short” serve as your control group? That is how you defined your control group in your first run. To be clear, this variable should be omitted from your output entirely; it is the referent.

Comment: Now I am a bit confused. What should the 'lm' model look like with 'short' serving as the control group?

Comment: In your original post, any homes *within* the 5-mile cutoff serve as your control group. They represent households *close to* the stadium, correct? If the answer is yes, then "short" is simply standing in for those households in the vicinity of the structure. Let me know if this is unclear, or if you need me to recommend some R code.

Comment: A example in R code of what you are describing would be great.

Comment: I updated my response. Let's jump in a chat if anything is still unclear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122700/discussion-between-bcongelio-and-thomas-bilach).